# Open folder in new instance

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to open a folder in a new instance of Excel. So far I have the following code:

```
Dim newexcel as New Excel.Application
```

Now I want to open a folder in my directory so that it is up to my choosing which file I pick.

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenFileDialog VBA (Powerpoint) Initial Directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537439/openfiledialog-vba-powerpoint-initial-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Try the

```
Application.Getopenfilename
```

This opens the dialogue for picking files. If you want to dispaly a specific folder, use this code before the Getopenfilename:

```
chdir "c:\whatever\wherever"
```

Are you sure you need a separate instance of Excel? It has many disadvantages, and only a few advantages.

Comment: What are the disadvantages?

Comment: Separate Excel instances can not "communicate", so you can't easily reference functions from one file to another, and you can not easily run macros across them. You will have less options when copy/pasting from one instance to another. And also, it uses more system resources. The *only* advantege I know of is that this way you can put Excel 2007/2010 windows on different monitors. If this is not needed, then there really is no reason to relaunch Excel.